# JavaScript element does not display on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, hide, mouseover, mouseout

I have two elements. One is "menu1" and is designed to unhide "atlas_menu1" on mouseover, and hide it on mouseout. My issue is that I also want "atlas_menu1" to stay unhidden when the mouse is over itself as well, but it isn't working. Here is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.a = document.getElementById("menu1"); 
window.e = document.getElementById("atlas_menu1"); 
a.onmouseover=function(){ e.style.display = "block"; };
a.onmouseout=function(){ e.style.display = "none"; };
e.onmouseover=function(){ e.style.display = "block"; };
e.onmouseout=function(){ e.style.display = "none"; }; 
</script>
```

Any thoughts as to how this could be done correctly? Here is the website to see, if you hover over the menu option "Who We Are" you will see the menu come down, but on hover over the menu it disappears. http://linden.flywheelsites.com

Comment: use .onmouseenter instead.

Comment: Just put that in there, and now it won't go away when the mouse leaves.

Comment: you can do the logic. just add a mouseleave function to your altas_menu1 and hide it again.

Comment: Which I did, naturally....but for some reason the code isn't firing and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What do you mean by : **I also want "atlas_menu1" to stay unhidden when the mouse is over itself as well.**

Answer (score 0):

```
#hiddenpanel{
 width: 150px;
 height:150px;
 background: green;
 display: inline-block;
 display: none;
}
```

here is a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/huspg48w/2/

Answer (score 0):

This **should do the trick.**

**Sample code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
<h3 onmouseover="" onmouseout="" id="menu1">Menu</h3>
<h3 onmouseover="" onmouseout="" id="atlas_menu1">Sub Menu</h3>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   window.a = document.getElementById("menu1"); 
   window.e = document.getElementById("atlas_menu1"); 
   a.onmouseover=function(){ e.style.display = "block"; };
   a.onmouseout=function(){ e.style.display = "none"; };
   e.onmouseover=function(){ e.style.display = "block"; };
   e.onmouseout=function(){ e.style.display = "none"; }; 
</script>
```

The above code is an example of a menu on hover shows a sub menu.